# Detecting overlap for buffered lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, line, overlapping-features

We have almost 50000+ lines which we want to remove a line if it is too close to the other.

So we tried to do a buffer for two line, then check if the buffer area are overlapped.

I wonder if there is a efficient idea to make it?

Since at my first thought, we need almost 50000*(50000-1) times detect for two buffered area, it will take a long long time plus the buffer time for a line. :(

---

We use ArcGIS, but we prefer to make it by program rather than through the UI.

Also, we will give a certain distance of meters or pixels to tell the program if the two line are too close to each other.

Comment: I think your Question will be more likely to attract answerers if you include a diagram to indicate how you define your lines as being "too close".

Comment: When you say "we prefer to make it by program" do you mean ArcPy/Python, ArcObjects, or something else?  I am suspecting that this Question may not be about buffering at all and that you may be wanting to do something more like [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000).  What format are these lines stored in?  What level license and version of ArcGIS for Desktop do you have access to?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is [Generate Near Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000) which will give you a table describing which features are close to other features.

[image]

Give the same feature class for *input features* and *near features* and supply your search distance (too close distance) in the search radius.

This gives you a table of which features are too close to other features:

[image]

The tool is intelligent enough to not give 0 distance if the In_Fid = Near_Fid. You might want to get rid of the lines were *distance = 0* as they are intersecting/touching.

It is not clear from your question on how to decide is which one to remove as the table will duplicate each distance: Feature A to B and B to A... this might be worthy of a new GIS.SE question when you decide on a rule to remove one or the other.

You can join this to your table using OBJECTID/FID to IN_FID to select the lines that are too close!